# video is stop after clicking cross button but start again after few seconds automatically in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I want to show a video in modal. The video is shown perfectly and while I clicked the cross button, modal is hide and video is stopped. But after few seconds video starts automatically from back-end.

**Here is my modal with the scripts**

```
{{-- start modal --}}
<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h1>Technology video</h1>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <iframe width="100%" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HBdcL7YsdBY?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{{-- end model  --}}
{{-- start script --}}
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('#videoModal').modal('show');

        jQuery("#videoModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) 
        {
            jQuery("#videoModal iframe").attr("src", jQuery("#videoModal iframe").attr("src"));
        });

    });
</script>
{{-- end script --}}
```

Why the video starts automatically? how to stop this?

Anybody help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

success !!

just replace

`jQuery("#videoModal iframe").attr("src", jQuery("#videoModal iframe").attr("src"));`

by

```
jQuery("#videoModal iframe").attr("src", jQuery("#videoModal iframe").attr("src", ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#videoModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) 
    {
        jQuery("#videoModal iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/HBdcL7YsdBY?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=0");
    });
jQuery("#videoModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) 
    {
        jQuery("#videoModal iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/HBdcL7YsdBY?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1");
    });
```